# How to use buttons to get realm data in a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, button, realm

I am new to android studio and I am stuck with buttons.  So all my data is stored in realm and I am using buttons and a ListView to show that data.  How would I do that? I originally was using the tab layout but it wasn't functioning properly.

How should I use buttons to show my realm data in list view?

Comment: Would you explain more? I don't have any clue what you mean. Specify what are buttons for? if you only want to show items in list you need to just query the realm and then feed your adapter with those items before you close the realm instance.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish, and what is the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Ok so I am using the phones calendar events using realm and taking the events and displaying them in the app.  I have three buttons Today's Event This week's Events and All Events.  I want to be able to click on today's events and have all the events appear for that day. Same with the week = all weeks events and all events = all events in calendar.